# Wix project, MajorUpgrade "AllowDowngrades = yes" is not working

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my Wix project, I have set

    `<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="yes" />`

but when I run the .msi for the second time, there is still an error message box preventing it from running.

What else should I set to run? Any specific version? (I don't think so because I already allow downgrade.)

Is it possible to let Wix (or even Windows installer) to run any version of the .msi file (earlier version, older version, same version) at any time?

Thanks,
Fei

Comment: Which error message you have? Do you run 2 times the same msi?

Comment: You cannot run the same MSI file twice. Once it has been installed you cannot run the same MSI again. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PhilDW I would like to let the user run any version of the .msi file any time: earlier version, older version, same version, it should not matter to the user.

Comment: You should show more of your source. To allow upgrades and downgrades you need the same upgradecode, different product and package code guids for every MSI, and a version change in the first 3 fields of the version.